# Phpseclib KeyUsage

Tags: php, ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate, phpseclib

Default certificate file created by PhpSecLib has keyUsage set to: `All rules of applications`. How could I set keyUsage to `digitalSignature` that Windows Crypto Shell will show: `Ensures the Identity of a remote computer`

**EDIT**

Here is my code:

```
<?php
include('File/X509.php');
include('Crypt/RSA.php');
$c = $_POST['csr'];

$CAPrivKey = new Crypt_RSA();
$CAPrivKey->setPassword('[...]');
$CAPrivKey->loadKey("-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
[...]
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
");

$issuer = new File_X509();
$issuer->setPrivateKey($CAPrivKey);
$issuer->loadX509("-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
[...]
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
");


$subject = new File_X509();

$subject->loadCSR($c); 


$x509 = new File_X509();
$x509->setStartDate('-1 month');
$x509->setEndDate('+1 year');
$x509->setSerialNumber('125');
$result = $x509->sign($issuer, $subject);


$x509->loadX509($result);
$x509->setExtension('id-ce-keyUsage', array_merge($x509->getExtension('id-ce-   keyUsage'), array('digitalSignature')));
$result = $x509->sign($issuer, $x509);
//echo $x509->saveX509($result);

header('Content-Type: application/x-x509-ca-cert');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='ssl.cer'");
echo $x509->saveX509($result);

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you post your cert? Because when I use your program it's totally not doing that for me.  My code:

```
<?php
include('File/X509.php');
include('Crypt/RSA.php');

$c = '-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
MIIBVjCBwgIAMB4xHDAaBgNVBAoME3BocHNlY2xpYiBkZW1vIGNlcnQwgZ0wCwYJKoZIhvcNAQEB
A4GNADCBiQKBgQDF+1/N2DwvdkhoHsLq8LnH99AEGVOGpooSpbPCewbuZeqr/Djb9ySPar2PLySo
Y+kB2QAbxUgpO/57IpWIabQ9jDFIznqLCcLzXKiKOWnMv4KMf55yJ6pwlqoTbUPgyQ67CRAfjcaD
W9VQ/TzdKahdxLFPBAEIEpEX23YpLhTLNQIDAQABMAsGCSqGSIb3DQEBBQOBgQALjJE4OygjvLm0
rzFyMPvAo7Ux6z5qTOi//HQzzmjNun7MV09GTfZgcYeWvuLosJXcn7CPALF5FqHWePs98WioTA7K
WsvdZzm+yJ5UcmzdJ/Jq9X8o1KTsMELN0SQwiNk502a1wbiXotF4OgCsjSdno96PCV9VSF4w69HM
1eXfvg==
-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----';


$CAPrivKey = new Crypt_RSA();
$CAPrivKey->loadKey('-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----');

$issuer = new File_X509();
$issuer->setPrivateKey($CAPrivKey);
$issuer->loadX509("-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----");


$subject = new File_X509();

$subject->loadCSR($c); 


$x509 = new File_X509();
$x509->setStartDate('-1 month');
$x509->setEndDate('+1 year');
$x509->setSerialNumber('125');
$result = $x509->sign($issuer, $subject);


$x509->loadX509($result);
$x509->setExtension('id-ce-keyUsage', array('digitalSignature'));
//$x509->setExtension('id-ce-keyUsage', array_merge($x509->getExtension('id-ce-keyUsage'), array('digitalSignature')));
$result = $x509->sign($issuer, $x509);
//echo $x509->saveX509($result);

header('Content-Type: application/x-x509-ca-cert');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='ssl.cer'");
echo $x509->saveX509($result);
```

Screenshot:

[image: the cert as displayed in windows]

The cert itself:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

So like I said, it's working just fine for me.

Maybe you can post the cert you're getting when you try to run it? Maybe you can post the CSR you're using as well?

Comment: Well, I got same, but now I am a bit confused. I misunderstood something. I am curious how to change description which appears on General tab.

Comment: I'm not seeing much of a description, myself, on the General tab. Here's what I'm seeing: http://i.stack.imgur.com/LJpiS.jpg Can you post a screenshot of what you're seeing?

Comment: First try to install, and everything will show up. I can't send you screenshot because I don't have English version of Windows.

Comment: I only have that issue when the signing cert is installed but I don't know what's causing it. As per the Details tab the cert's key uses are digital signature only. I don't know what the General tab is showing.  Maybe it's derived somehow from the signing cert - not sure. I'd ask on superuser.com maybe. That seems almost like a Windows admin question..

Comment: Look there: http://www.themidnightcoders.com/fileadmin/docs/dotnet/v5/certificate_details.png

Comment: I still stand by my earlier statement that this is more of a Windows question than anything. As I noted, the General tab is basing what it's showing off of more than just what's in the cert. We already have one example where having the signing cert imported changes what's being displayed. That's an example of something that's beyond phpseclib's purview. phpseclib can only help you with generating certs - it can't import them for you. That said, I am trying to find out for you. To wit I made these posts: http://tinyurl.com/czaonln and http://tinyurl.com/cc2vgdd

Comment: Do this: `$x509->setExtension('id-ce-extKeyUsage', array('id-kp-serverAuth'));` The bit about what you have to do to get it working in OpenSSL is what tipped me off.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you're resigning a cert you'll need to create your cert by doing an $x509->sign() first. Then you'll need to reload that cert, set the extension, resign it and save it. eg.

```
<?php
include('File/X509.php');
include('Crypt/RSA.php');

$privKey = new Crypt_RSA();
$privKey->loadKey('...');

$pubKey = new Crypt_RSA();
$pubKey->loadKey($privKey->getPublicKey());
$pubKey->setPublicKey();

$subject = new File_X509();
$subject->setDNProp('id-at-organizationName', 'demo cert');
$subject->setPublicKey($pubKey);

$issuer = new File_X509();
$issuer->setPrivateKey($privKey);
$issuer->setDN($subject->getDN());

$x509 = new File_X509();
//$x509->makeCA();
$x509->setSerialNumber('1');

$result = $x509->sign($issuer, $subject);
$x509->loadX509($result);
$x509->setExtension('id-ce-keyUsage', array('digitalSignature'));
//$x509->setExtension('id-ce-keyUsage', array_merge($x509->getExtension('id-ce-keyUsage'), array('digitalSignature')));
$result = $x509->sign($issuer, $x509);
echo $x509->saveX509($result);
?>
```

It'd be nice if the whole resigning thing was unnecessary but whatever. I'll see if I can get the phpseclib author to make some revisions to it at some point.

Comment: Ok, it generates, but when I try to open it it shows value: `N/A` in KeyUsage field

Comment: I updated my post to include the full code I was using. If you're having issues posting the code would be helpful for me to diagnose them. Like maybe you're doing makeCA()? There are a lot of possible permutations and I don't want to try all of them.. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When I tried to run your code I got a bunch of errors. Mainly due to this line:

```
$x509->setExtension('id-ce-keyUsage', array_merge($x509->getExtension('id-ce-   keyUsage'), array('digitalSignature')));
```

Two problems with that:

1. You have spaces between id-ce- and keyUsage. Those spaces shouldn't be there.
2. array_merge will return NULL if getExtension returns NULL. ie. if that extension is undefined. As such what you'll need to do is this:

   ```
   $x509->setExtension('id-ce-keyUsage', array('digitalSignature'));
   ```

Comment: Yea, thanks. I am curious which field determines that Windows will claim usage of  certificate as `Ensures the Identity of a remote computer`, because it still shows: `All rules of applications` and `digitalSignature` in properties. For OpenSSL it worked.

Comment: It works fine for me as my second answer demonstrates. To sum that post up... can you post your cert and the CSR you're using to get it? Also, thinking about it.. what version of Windows are you using? I'm using Windows 7..